# Vertical Tabs with Vertical Text in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of .jpeg menu tabs, which contain vertical text, and are oriented vertically (height > width). Attempting to create vertical tabs, such that they go from the top to the bottom of the screen in series, but after reading some documentation, I'm still not sure exactly where to start. Any tips? Sorry for the extremely vague question, but most search results assume you want a vertical menu with horizontal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browser compatibility is not a priority, you can try using CSS3:

```
.rotated-text {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
    transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); /* Should work on IE9+ */
}
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/C3qrT/**

Then you must work to align text as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` combined with a narrow `width` value to force your text to wrap for every single letter: http://jsbin.com/ominus/1/edit

Rotating would look better, but it's another option!